# tableView in XCode is returning cells with random data from array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, tableview

I am making a simple messaging app in xcode. The table view is populated with custom cells that contain a right and left view. When the user receives a message the left view is populated and when the user sends a message the right view is populated.

The PROBLEM is after reloading the tableView sometimes I will see cells filled with scrambled data from the array containing the messages. I'm not sure what is happening.

Things I've tried:

- I've checked the message files that are stored on my backend in Back4App and they all contain the corrent csv data
- I looked at my cell count which is always accurate
- I've printed the array and cell data before the table reloads and after it reloads and the data in the array's is all correct.
- If I leave the message VC and return to it all the messages are displayed correctly but when I stay in the VC and use the send button to send messages the data gets scrambled a little and prints weird combinations of my tableView

You can see the bottom line is not displayed correctly:
[Image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KHJ1.png)

Here is my chat VC:

```
//
//  ChatViewController.swift
//  Glam
//
//  Created by Student on 11/14/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Tucker Weibell. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navTitle: UINavigationItem!
    var senders = [String]()
    var message = [String]()
    var state = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var dataStringSender = ""
    var dataStringReciever = ""
    var senderName = ""
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData()
        navTitle.title = MessageCustomerViewController.GlobalVars.selectedItem
        
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    func getData() {
        let user = PFUser.current()
        let username = user?.username
        senderName = username!
        let query = PFUser.query()
        query?.whereKey("username", equalTo: username!)
        do {
            let result = try query?.findObjects()
            let file = result![0]["Messages"] as! PFFileObject
            do {
                let data = try file.getData()
                let string = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                dataStringSender = string
                let cvsRows = string.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                for row in cvsRows {
                    var itemsRow = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
                    print(itemsRow)
                    itemsRow[2] = itemsRow[2].replacingOccurrences(of: "\r", with: "")
                    print(itemsRow)
                    if itemsRow[0] == MessageCustomerViewController.GlobalVars.selectedItem {
                        senders.append(itemsRow[0])
                        message.append(itemsRow[1])
                        state.append(itemsRow[2])
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        loadData()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let query = PFUser.query()
        query?.whereKey("username", equalTo: MessageCustomerViewController.GlobalVars.selectedItem)
        do {
            let result = try query?.findObjects()
            if result?[0]["Messages"] != nil {
                let file = result![0]["Messages"] as! PFFileObject
                do {
                    let data = try file.getData()
                    let string = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                    dataStringReciever = string
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        dataStringSender = dataStringSender + "\n" + MessageCustomerViewController.GlobalVars.selectedItem + "," + textView.text + "," + "Sent"
        dataStringReciever = dataStringReciever + "\n" + senderName + "," + textView.text + "," + "Recieved"
        
        let dataSent = Data(dataStringSender.utf8)
        let dataRecieved = Data(dataStringReciever.utf8)
        //let fileSent: PFFileObject = PFFileObject(data: dataSent)!
        //let fileRecieved: PFFileObject = PFFileObject(data: dataRecieved)!
        
        
        let fileSent = PFFileObject(name: "message.csv", data: dataSent)
        
        let fileRecieved = PFFileObject(name: "message.csv", data: dataRecieved)
        
        let user = PFUser.current()
        user!["Messages"] = fileSent
        user?.saveInBackground()
        
        let newQuery = PFUser.query()
        newQuery?.whereKey("username", equalTo: MessageCustomerViewController.GlobalVars.selectedItem)
        do {
            let newResults = try newQuery?.findObjects()
            newResults![0]["Messages"] = fileRecieved
            newResults![0].saveInBackground()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        clearData()
        getData()
        print("\n")
        print("\n")
        print(message)
        print("\n")
        print("\n")
        print(state)
        loadData()
        
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func clearData() {
        message.removeAll()
        state.removeAll()
        senders.removeAll()
    }
    
    
    @objc func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            var height = keyboardRectangle.height
            height = height * -1
            bottomConstraint.constant = height + 85
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func dismissKeyboard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return message.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
            print([message[indexPath.row]])
    
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messagescell") as! MessagesCell
        
            if state[indexPath.row] == "Sent" {
                cell.sentText.text = message[indexPath.row]
                cell.sentView.backgroundColor = .clear
            }
            else {
                cell.recievedText.text = message[indexPath.row]
                cell.recievedView.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: You can debug by putting a breakpoint in cellForRowAt indexPath: how cell text is getting modified. For sent you can clear recievedText and for received you can clear sentText by setting empty string.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like an reusable cell issue.

Since you are reusing your cells here `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messagescell") as! MessagesCell` the properties of those cells happen to have old states from time to time if you not explicitly set new values to all of them.

You should override `prepareForReuse()` in your custom cell implementation and reset your cell to default values.